# Can't copy into my own Public folder

Tags: finder, file-sharing

I can't copy into my own Public folder neither with my finder nor from terminal 'sudo cp ~/temp/gyongyinek/* ~/Public/'

If I execute the above command from terminal I got this:
Operation not permitted
If I want to copy from finder then the crossed out mouse cursor appears suggesting that the operation is invalid...

This is my Public directory access flag:
drwxr-xr-x+  3 boti  staff     204 Jan 11  2012 Public

If on finder I hit Command+I then I have the following access rules:
Fetching: Read Only
Fetching: Read Only
boti(Me): Read & Write
staff: Read Only
everyone: Read Only

Comment: I also checked the disk permissions but they were ok.

Comment: Ohh... The folder was locked... Sorry for the stupid question....

Comment: Can you post it as an answer so the question won't get bumped up later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution
The folder was locked...